# Alternative to Objective-C objects in structs (ARC)

Tags: objective-c, struct, automatic-ref-counting

I have the following code here that won't run on ARC since it combines Objective-C objects in structs:

```
struct SingleToManyRelation {
    id singleObject;
    NSSet* manyObjects;
}
```

I know this is reminiscent of Core Data, but that's not the point ;) I am just looking for a solution to implement something like that without having to create a "container" class.

Thanks in advance for your advices,
Christian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give your objects the `__unsafe_unretained` attribute and ARC will stop complaining (but keep in mind that they aren't retained! So you have to somehow store a strong relationship to them, if you don't want to lose them)

Comment: @cschwarz and that solution was?