# Fixing ARC error when using Objective-C object in struct

Tags: xcode

I am having an issue with my Xcode project.

I have these lines:

```
typedef struct
{
    NSString *escapeSequence;
    unichar uchar;
}
```

and I am getting this error:

> ARC forbids Objective-C objects in structs or unions.

How can I fix it?

I cannot seem to find how this violates ARC but I would love to learn.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative to Objective-C objects in structs (ARC)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055404/alternative-to-objective-c-objects-in-structs-arc)

Comment: Also: [ARC forbids Objective-C objects in structs or unions despite marking the file -fno-objc-arc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093099/arc-forbids-objective-c-objects-in-structs-or-unions-despite-marking-the-file-f), [Objective-C classes in structs with ARC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851870/objective-c-classes-in-structs-with-arc), [the ARC documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership-qualified-fields-of-structs-and-unions).

Comment: brother, did u use the above code for epub reader. If so pls guide me to convert it to arc. It would be extremely helpful for me.

Answer (score 34):

Change it to:

```
typedef struct
{
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *escapeSequence;
    unichar uchar;
}MyStruct;
```

But, I recommend following Apple rules from [this documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).

> **ARC Enforces New Rules**
>
> You cannot use object pointers in C structures.
>   Rather than using a struct, you can create an Objective-C class to manage the data instead.

Comment: This response is outdated. As of WWDC '18, you are now allowed to specify ARC object pointers in C structs.

Comment: It appears that at least __strong and __weak are now supported in structs by clang (2019).

Answer (score 8):

The safest way is to use `__unsafe_unretained` or directly `CFTypeRef` and then use the `__bridge`, `__bridge_retained` and `__bridge_transfer`.

e.g

```
typedef struct Foo {
    CFTypeRef p;
} Foo;

int my_allocating_func(Foo *f)
{
    f->p = (__bridge_retained CFTypeRef)[[MyObjC alloc] init];
    ...
}

int my_destructor_func(Foo *f)
{
    MyObjC *o = (__bridge_transfer MyObjC *)f->p;
    ...
    o = nil; // Implicitly freed
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When we are defining C structure in Objective C with ARC enable, we get the error "ARC forbids Objective-C objects in struct". In that case, we need to use keyword `__unsafe_unretained`.

Example

```
struct Books{

    NSString *title;
    NSString *author;
    NSString *subject;
    int book_id;
};
```

Correct way to use in ARC enable projects:

```
struct Books{

    __unsafe_unretained NSString *title;
   __unsafe_unretained NSString *author;
   __unsafe_unretained NSString *subject;
   int book_id;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I just integrated the same code into my project from the Google Toolbox for Mac

[GTMNSString-HTML.m](https://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSString%2BHTML.m)

Their suggestion for [ARC Compatibility](https://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/wiki/ARC_Compatibility) of adding the `-fno-objc-arc` flag to each file worked for me.

Comment: brother, did u use the above code for epub reader. If so pls guide me to convert it to arc. It would be extremely helpful for me....