# how to make an objective c class to handle a struct?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, struct

Basically, I don't know much `C++`, and I've been trying to implement the leaderboard code from the [friendSmasher sample project](https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-friend-smash-v2/tree/master/friendsmash)  on github. After searching for some related posts, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14784973/fixing-arc-error-when-using-objective-c-object) which recommended creating an `Objective-C` class to manage the data instead. Below is the relevant code from the project. How can I make an objective-c class(es) to manage the data?

```
struct LeaderboardboardInstance
{
System::Sprite* pStubSprite;
UILabel *pFriendName;
UILabel *pFriendScore;
System::TextureResource* pUserTexture;
System::Sprite* pUserSprite;
};
```

Also I believe the `System::Sprite* abc` and the other `System` calls are `C++` libraries and would like to know the equivalent classes in `Objective-C` that I should use.

Comment: The recommendation is for the case when your struct contains any Objective-C objects.

Comment: I was getting them the same error `ARC forbids Objective-C objects in structs` since UILabel is Objective-C